# get API documentation for Clojure libraries

Tags: api, clojure, documentation, libraries

I'm new to Clojure, and I would like to know where is all the documentation
for all the libraries such as those found on [clojars.org](https://clojars.org/)?

for example using lein I do the following to the project.clj

```
(defproject Program-name "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
   [facts/speech-synthesis "1.0.0"]
[org.clojars.jeffsigmon/maryclient "4.3.0"]
[speech-synthesis "1.0.0"]
[clarity "0.5.6"]])
```

then use`lein deps` to install all the libraries

Core.clj

```
(ns Program-name.core
(:use [speech-synthesis.say :as say])(use [clarity.component]))
(use 'clarity.form)
```

so how would I import and get the API information for org.clojars.jeffsigmon/maryclient?

> note: I read that that the API documentation is stored in the
>   libraries and you have to import them to access it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API docs are in the code in the form of docstrings

e.g.

```
(defn my-func
 "This is the doc string"
 [a b c]
   ...)
```

You can access the doc strings in the REPL:

```
$ lein repl
user> (doc println)
-------------------------
clojure.core/println
([& more])
  Same as print followed by (newline)

user> (apropos "print")
(*print-radix* *print-miser-width* *print-pprint-dispatch* print-table 
  print-length-loop pprint-indent pprint *print-suppress-namespaces* 
  *print-right-margin* *print-pretty* with-pprint-dispatch ...)

user> (find-doc "print")
... lots of functions related to print with docs...
```

Various IDEs also give access to the docs. e.g. in emacs, with swank you can use `slime-describe-symbol` accessed via the shortcut `C-c C-d d`

Answer (score 2):

use `doc`, `find-doc`, `apropos` function on REPL, use `lein repl` start a repl.
BTW: if the library jar is not include .clj files, you cannot use them.